# If has class then remove class and add class

Tags: jquery, css, html

Having an issue here. This should be working... I have 4 elements in html that look like this

```
    <!-- Light Color Scheme - Header False and Show Faces True -->
        <div class="fb-like-box h-f_dsf-t visible" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Alpine-Adaptive-Scholarship-Program/344942928870040?fref=ts" data-width="292" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="false" colorscheme="light"></div>
```

Although they are in different variations. So one could be header true and show faces true and the unique class would be ".h-t_dsf-t". The javascript should pick between them and tell which one is active and which one isn't. So only one has the .visible class at a time and the others have a .invisible class.

Thanks in advance!

My Javascript For The Show Faces Button ***(note .sf-no.click doesn't have anything in it yet but it will in the future I was just trying to get it to work for the yes button first.)***

```
// Show Faces
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sf-yes').click(
        function() {
            $('.sf-yes').removeClass('btn-not-active btn-active').addClass('btn-active');
            $('.sf-no').removeClass('btn-not-active btn-active').addClass('btn-not-active');
            // Show Faces Yes &&& Show Header No
            if ($('.sf-yes.sh-no').hasClass('.btn-active')) {
                $('.h-f_dsf-t').removeClass('.invisible').addClass('.visible');
                $('.visible').removeClass('.visible').addClass('.invisible');
            }
            // Show Faces Yes &&& Show Header Yes
            if ($('.sf-yes.sh-yes').hasClass('.btn-active')) {
                $('.visible').removeClass('.visible').addClass('.invisible');
                $('.h-t_dsf-t').removeClass('.invisible').addClass('.visible');
            }
            // Show Faces No &&& Show Header Yes
            if ($('.sf-no.sh-yes').hasClass('.btn-active')) {
                $('.visible').removeClass('.visible').addClass('.invisible');
                $('.h-t_dsf-f').removeClass('.invisible').addClass('.visible');
            }
            // Show Faces No &&& Show Header No
            if ($('.sf-no.sh-no').hasClass('.btn-active')) {
                $('.visible').removeClass('.visible').addClass('.invisible');
                $('.h-f_dsf-f').removeClass('.invisible').addClass('.visible');
            }
        }
    );
    $('.sf-no').click(
        function() {
            $('.sf-no').removeClass('btn-not-active btn-active').addClass('btn-active');
            $('.sf-yes').removeClass('btn-not-active btn-active').addClass('btn-not-active');
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.hasClass('.btn-active')`

should be

`.hasClass('btn-active')`

without dot `.`

Comment: @user1844077 it's difficult to understand what you try to do. This is the only error that I've seen. If it still not works then there is some logical error. Try to reproduce it in a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few problems with your included code. When you remove a class or add a class, you shouldn't include the fullstop. `.` You have done this on `.hasClass`, `removeClass`, and `addClass`.

Additionally your conditional statements seem to be contradictory. Perhaps you actually mean what you say, but I am assuming that the elements that include the classes `.sf-yes` and `.sh-no` are two different elements. Your jQuery statement is looking for an element with both those classes.

It is also worth nothing that selectors using a class is not the best practice and you should use unique id's such as `#sf-yes`. Alternatively if you must use multiple class selectors, then assign each to a variable at the start of your function call.

Finally, I don't think you should tag this as a Facebook question as your code is regarding jQuery specifically.